# Is $C^{\infty}_c (R^d)$ dense in $C_c(R^d)$? Proof?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is $C^{\infty}_c (R^d)$ dense in $C_c(R^d)$?

with $C_c(R^d)$ the space of continuous functions $R^d \rightarrow R$, that have compact support.

If yes, do you have a proof?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is.

You can prove it by convoluting $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ functions with a smooth and compactly supported approximation of unity (also called [mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)). This gives a smooth uniform approximation of the original function.

The same argument shows that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $1\le p<\infty$.

Comment: Some details this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242877/compact-support-functions-dense-in-l-1/242895?noredirect=1#comment1402033_242895