# Does $\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)\, dx=0$ imply that $f=0$ a.e. without assuming $f \in C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f \in L^{1}[0,1]$ and $\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)\, dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$
Does that imply that $f=0$ a.e.?

I think that there will be a counterexample but it is hard to find out.

Comment: Take $f(0)=42$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in(0,1]$. Then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$, yet $f$ is not nil (only nil almost everywhere).

Comment: What is your definition of "$=0$"? Is it "$=0$" in the sense of $L^1$ (that is, $=0$ a.e.) or "$=0$" in the sense of functions (that is, $=0$ everywhere)? In the latter case the answer is no, through simple examples whose support is one point. In the former case I think the answer is yes. The easiest argument is probably approximation by continuous functions.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32369/functions-orthogonal-to-xn

Comment: @mt_ Good reference. But $f \in L^{1}$ doesn't have to be in $L^2$.

Comment: $$
\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\,{\rm f}\left(\, x\,\right)\,{\rm d}x = 0
$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumptions imply that $\int p(x) f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all polynomials $p$.

Now, by the (Stone)-Weierstraß Theorem, every **continuous** function $g \in C([0,1])$ is a uniform limit of polynomials. This yields (how exactly?) $\int g(x) f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all continuous functions $g \in C([0,1])$.

Now, every $g \in L^\infty ([0,1]) \subset L^1([0,1])$ can be approximated (in the $L^1$-norm) by a sequence of continuous functions $(g_n)_n$ (see e.g. [Compact support functions dense in $L_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242877/compact-support-functions-dense-in-l-1)). For a suitable subsequence (again denoted by $(g_n)_n$), this implies convergence almost everywhere (see e.g. [$L^1$ convergence gives a pointwise convergent subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714744/l1-convergence-gives-pointwise-convergent-subsequence)).

By considering $h_n := \min \{\Vert g \Vert_\infty, \max\{ - \Vert g \Vert_\infty, g_n\} \}$, you can assume that the sequence $(h_n)_n)$ is uniformily bounded and converges to $g$ almost everywhere.

By dominated convergence (what is the dominating function?), this yields

$$
\int f(x) g(x) \, dx = \lim_n \int f(x) h_n(x) \, dx = 0.
$$

But if we now take $g = \chi_{\{x \mid f(x) \geq 0 \}}$, this implies (how?) $f \leq 0$ almost everywhere. An analogous argument yields $f \geq 0$ almost everywhere and hence $f \equiv 0 $ almost everywhere.