# Showing measurable function is zero a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence, weierstrass-approximation

I'm trying to solve the following old exam question from my analysis class:

Suppose $f$ is a compactly supported measurable function, such that for all integers $n\ge0$,
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)x^ndx=0
\end{equation}
Prove that $f(x)\equiv 0$ almost everywhere.

Here's my original line of thinking: if the support of $f(x)$ is contained in $[a,b]$, then it is straightforward to show $f\in L^1([a,b])$. Thus $f$ can be approximated by continuous functions, and continuous functions are uniformly approximated by polynomials, so we can show $f\equiv 0$ in $L^1$.

The problem is, I don't know how to make this argument precise. When I try to write it out, I end up with a sequence of continuous functions that seem to converge to $f$, but it's unclear if they converge uniformly to $0$.

Is this a good approach to solving this problem? Is there a way to make this approach precise?

Comment: @AnneBauval: thank you! We have not (yet) learned about Fourier series. So I think your link does answer the question, but I'd be interested if there are ways to avoid using Fourier series.

Comment: I think it might be better if you tell us what tools you have available.

Comment: @Jose27: I'm not sure how to answer that. Our class just started, so what I have available is the analysis I already know. I don't know anything about Fourier series, but it seems we might learn something about it. I think (selfishly) it would be interesting to know if there was a solution using just my knowledge, but I think it's acceptable to say "there's not".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)\, dx=0$ imply that $f=0$ a.e. without assuming $f \in C[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075818)

Comment: Yes, I think that's perfect, thanks!